# Why default index in oracle is called B-tree but not B+tree?

Tags: oracle, indexing, b-tree

i have a question on Oracle default index, it is called B-tree,

This is from Oracle Doc,

```
B-Tree Indexes
B-trees, short for balanced trees, are the most common type of database index. A B-tree index is an 
ordered list of values divided into ranges. By associating a key with a row or range of rows, B-trees 
provide excellent retrieval performance for a wide range of queries, including exact match and range 
searches.

A B-tree index has two types of blocks: branch blocks for searching and leaf blocks that store 
values.
```

from that description, i feel it is more like B+tree, as for B+tree, only leaf node store date, the branch just store keys pointing to leaf nodes,

then why it is stated the default index for Oracle is B-tree but not B+tree?

Comment: I have not heard of a "B+tree" index, can you provide a reference for that term?  All attempts to Google it just return pages about B-tree indexes.

Comment: [Do you mean this?](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%2B_tree) Its unfamiliarity as a term, which seems to just refer to a subset of B-tree, might explain why it isn't used in the documentation?

Comment: i mysql, the index used is B+tree, i feel the index used in oracle is the same, don't know why it is not call B+tree, but just B-tree, is it because B+tree is a version of B-tree ?

Comment: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/204561/does-mysql-use-b-tree-btree-or-both

Comment: The accepted answer on that question seems may cover it: "Well, not all MySQL users are supposed to know what B+Tree is. This may be an oversimplification, but in that context it seems to me acceptable.". Assuming Oracle is B+, which seems likely, from my extensive (10+ minutes!) knowledge of the difference *8-)

Comment: "i mysql, the index used is B+tree, i feel the index used in oracle is the same, don't know why it is not call B+tree, "  From an oracle perspective I could just as easily turn that around to "In oracle, the index used is B-tree, I feel the index used in MySQL is the same, don't know why it is called B+tree".